# HTTP POST request in iOS

Tags: ios

hi i am new in ios and i didn't send any call to php till now today i have tried by the following code

```
-(void)sendRequest
{

NSString *vali = @"$uppl!3r$";

NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"key1=%@",vali];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
NSLog(@"%@",postLength);
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.ddemo3.enerjinet.com/webservices/ios/suppliers.php"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

if (theConnection) {
    webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    NSLog(@"%@",webData);
}
else
{

}
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
  {
        [webData setLength: 0];
   }

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
[webData appendData:data];

}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
[connection release];
[webData release];

}
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSString *loginStatus = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes] length:                       [webData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",loginStatus);
//greeting.text = loginStatus;
[loginStatus release];
[connection release];
[webData release];
}
```

it should return me array of 76 records but it returns me `<>` can anyone please help me ? The web service is ready i need to get the array in response and show it in my table view please help me in doing this

Comment: Use `initWithData:encoding:` to create the string from the data.

Comment: i have added nslog and it go to the didfailwitherror why is that ? @Wain

Comment: i added it now and i got both `<>` and that ns log msg let me try your once @Rob

Comment: By the way, have you confirmed that your web service is actually working? Are you 100% sure the problem rests in this code? Sure, you're not handling all of the possible error conditions properly, but you first want to make sure the server code is working correctly.

Comment: At first, check the length of *webData* that you receive. If it is not zero it looks like improper choice of encoding while converting from *NSData* to *NSString*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of thoughts:

1. You `NSLog` your `webData`, which will always show `<>` (as your logging it immediately after instantiated it). I'm not sure why you're logging that.

The question is whether you're seeing that `<>`, or the `NSLog` in `connectionDidFinishLoading`.

2. I ask that because you are not logging the `error` in `connection:didFailWithError:`, if it fails, you'll never know why. You really should log the `error` in `connection:didFailWithError:` so you know if it failed, and if so, why:

   ```
    NSLog(@"%s: %@", __FUNCTION__, error);
   ```
3. In your `connection:didReceiveResponse:`, you really should look at the [HTTP status code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html):

   ```
    if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]]) {
        NSInteger statusCode = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode];

        if (statusCode != 200)
            NSLog(@"%s: status code is %d; should be 200", __FUNCTION__, statusCode);
    }
   ```

If it's not 200, you really want to know about that.

4. You report in one of your comments that you are seeing `connectionDidFinishLoading:` called, but never having `didReceiveData` called. That means (unsurprisingly) that there was no data received. So, you should:

- Confirm that the `connection:didReceiveResponse:` reported a `statusCode` of `200`; and
- Confirm that the server code is working properly. I could imagine getting the behavior you describe if you had an error in your server PHP code (which is exacerbated by the fact that servers often have `display_errors` turned off in their `php.ini` file).

---

As an aside, if it's possible that the value associated with `key1` might contain any reserved characters (as defined in [section 2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2) of RFC 3986), you should percent-escape the string using `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes`. Thus:

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"key1=%@", [self percentEscapeString:vali]];
```

Where, per the [W3C specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#application/x-www-form-urlencoded-encoding-algorithm) for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, you not only percent escape, but also replace spaces with `+` characters, thus:

```
- (NSString *)percentEscapeString:(NSString *)string
{ 
    NSString *result = CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                                                 (CFStringRef)string,
                                                                                 (CFStringRef)@" ",
                                                                                 (CFStringRef)@":/?@!$&'()*+,;=",
                                                                                 kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
    return [result stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
}
```

Comment: Firstly thanks it i nslog in connection fail and it showed me error that i resolve now it goes in the connectiondidfinishloading but it didnt go into the didreceivedata @rob

Comment: @user3089900 Updated answer (point #4) to reflect why you might see "finish loading" but not "did receive data".

Comment: the status code i got is 1003

Comment: @user3089900 Really?!? That's not a standard [HTTP status code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html). Something weird going on with your server code, methinks.

Comment: i hd sorted now its 200 but still its empty

Comment: @user3089900 Ok, the 200 code is good. That means that the server received the request successfully. Now the problem appears to be that your server code is not generating a response. You'll have to take a look at that PHP code now.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
+ (void)sendAsynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request queue:(NSOperationQueue *)queue completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLResponse*, NSData*, NSError*))handler
```

Unless you have a compelling reason not to.

Example (probably non-working):

Note creating `postData`.

```
-(void)sendRequest {
    NSString *vali = @"$uppl!3r$";
    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"key1=%@",vali];
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", [postData length]];
    NSLog(@"%@", postLength);

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.ddemo3.enerjinet.com/webservices/ios/suppliers.php"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

                               NSLog(@"data: %@", data);

                           }];
}
```

Oh, make life easier, use `ARC`.

Comment: If you want to find out what is happening get a network analyzer such as Charles Proxy (30 free trial) and look at what is being send and received. It is really fairly simple.