# NSURLSessionTask setting parameters with NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlrequest, nsurlsession

I'm almost certain that I recently saw an networking related method that allowed setting of URL parameters with an `NSDictionary`.

It was part of the new NSURLSession classes but I can't find it.

Essentially, instead of doing the url like...

```
@"www.blah.com/something.php?value=18&name=hello"
```

You could do...

```
theRequest.parameters = @{@"value":@18, @"name":@"hello"};
```

Am I imagining this or does this exist?

Comment: Check out this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21299362/is-there-any-way-to-attach-a-nsdictionary-of-parameters-to-an-nsurlrequest-inste?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: If it doesn't exist, why not write it? :)

Comment: [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) uses this pattern quite a bit. `NSURLSession` methods, themselves, don't take dictionaries as parameters to requests, but it's not hard to write the code to convert the dictionary into JSON or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` requests. But AFNetworking generally makes you life easier.

Comment: @Rob I have been thinking about using AFNetworking. I don't know if it's actually needed though. I'm starting a completely fresh project so I'll have a look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not write it your self?
you can use that, just keep the right order when you put the values into the dictionary.

```
- (NSString *)makeURLFromDictionary:(NSString *)url values:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
  {
NSMutableString *string = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:url];
[string appendString:@"?"];
for (id key in dictionary) {
    [string appendString:key];
    [string appendString:@"="];
    [string appendString:[dictionary objectForKey:key]];
    [string appendString:@"&"];
}
//this will remove the last &
[string deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange([string length]-1, 1)];

return string;
}
```

Please just check the returned string, if I'm not wrong you should put it in reverse way, F.I.L.O(First in Last Out style).

enter the dict's values like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[dict setObject:@"hello" forKey:@"name"];
[dict setObject:@"18" forKey:@"value"];

NSString *urlString = [self makeURLFromDictionary:@"www.blah.com/somthing.php" values:dict];
```

Hop i help you.

Comment: +1 BTW, make sure you call `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes` on the value you add after the `=` (as illustrated in the latter part of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21079176/1271826)).